# Excel Automatically update a row in another sheet

Tags: excel

I have a excel workbook with 3 sheets, sheet1 contains all the data which is split into remanning 2 sheets.

sheet1 data is updated on daily bases therefore i need to split sheet1 and update the reming two sheets, so at the moment i copy a each row from sheet1 and replace corresponding row in sheet2 or sheet3 with new data , each sheet contains the same columns: customer_id, customer_name, customer_surname, customer_deposit, total_deposits.

This requires so much manual work is there way where i can just automatically update a row in sheet2 
and sheet3 with the data from sheet1.

Ps. The customer_id never changes so maybe there is a way i could use this t update the rows....?

Comment: Why is the data from sheet1 copied into two other sheets?  Why not just use sheet1?

Comment: because the data in sheet1 in split into two teams

Answer (score 0):

If you only use sheet 2 & 3 for viewing the data then you can do something like this:

In sheet 2 set the formula for A1 to be

> =(Sheet1!A1)

then drag the cell to the left (copying the formula) for however many columns you want. Then drag the higlighted cells down to copy the formula to all the desired cells. Then do the same on sheet 3 but starting at the point you want to split sheet 1. Then update sheet 1 and sheet 2 and 3 will automatically update.

Comment: Note, if you add a new row, the information in that row will not automatically update to the other sheets. You will have to manually insert a corresponding row, and update the formula for that row.